# Update two dataframe column based on condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, conditional-statements

I Have a dataframe with columns as 'PK', 'Column1', 'Column2'. 
I want to update Column1 and Column2 as follows:

```
If Column1 > Column2 then (Column1 = Column1 - Column2) and at the same time Column2 = 0
```

Similarly

```
If Column1 < Column2 then (Column2 = Column2 - Column1) and at the same time Column1 = 0
```

I have tried with following but it is not giving expected result:

```
df["Column1"] = np.where(df['Column1'] > df['Column2'], df['Column1'] - df['Column2'], 0)
df["Column2"] = np.where(df['Column1'] < df['Column2'], df['Column2'] - df['Column1'], 0)
```

Comment: u could share some data as well,  to aid in the solution provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) for avoid testing overwriten column `Column1` in second line of your code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'Column1':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'Column2':[7,8,9,4,2,3],

})
print (df)
   Column1  Column2
0        4        7
1        5        8
2        4        9
3        5        4
4        5        2
5        4        3

a = np.where(df['Column1'] > df['Column2'], df['Column1'] - df['Column2'], 0)
b = np.where(df['Column1'] < df['Column2'], df['Column2'] - df['Column1'], 0)

df = df.assign(Column1 = a, Column2 = b)
print (df)
   Column1  Column2
0        0        3
1        0        3
2        0        5
3        1        0
4        3        0
5        1        0
```